# Is Hall conductivity time-reversal-odd at finite frequency in a topological system?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, topological-insulators, quantum-hall-effect

In some topological materials, e.g., the quantum (anomalous) Hall state and some related variants, the Hall conductivity $\sigma_{xy}$ is quantized and directly related to the Chern number, which corresponds to the number of chiral edge modes. In this sense, $\sigma_{xy}$ must be time-reversal-odd.

But this is the $\omega\rightarrow0$ limit. Does the time-reversal-oddness of $\sigma_{xy}$ still hold at finite frequency $\omega\neq0$?